# why in C, for unsigned data, right shifts must be logical?

Tags: c

Why in C, for unsigned data, right shifts must be logical?

This is from *Computer systems, a programmar's perspective*

Comment: The alternative would be what?

Comment: @HotLicks: Illogical right shifts! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

On an unsigned type, a logical shift and an arithmetic shift are identical.

Comment: Indeed, on any positive value they're identical... and if you use right shift on a negative value, the behaviour is implementation-defined, so technically the statement "right shifts must be logical" is invalid because right shifts *may* be otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Because SAR (arithmetic shift) fills the most significant bit according to the previous MSB bit before the shift, effectively handling it as a sign bit and preserving the correct sign, while a SHR (logical shift) simply clears it.

For an unsigned value where the MSB is set, if you shift right with intention to divide the value by 2, you want to fill in zeros from the MSB, otherwise the result would be meaningless. I'm assuming that's what the author meant, although it could have been explained better.

[link](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html):

> The shift arithmetic right (SAR) and shift logical right (SHR)
>   instructions shift the bits of the destination operand to the right
>   (toward less significant bit locations). For each shift count, the
>   least significant bit of the destination operand is shifted into the
>   CF flag, and the most significant bit is either set or cleared
>   depending on the instruction type. The SHR instruction clears the most
>   significant bit (see Figure 7-8 in the IA-32 Intel Architecture
>   Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1); the SAR instruction sets or
>   clears the most significant bit to correspond to the sign (most
>   significant bit) of the original value in the destination operand. In
>   effect, the SAR instruction fills the empty bit position's shifted
>   value with the sign of the unshifted value (see Figure 7-9 in the
>   IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1).
>
> The SAR and SHR instructions can be used to perform signed or unsigned
>   division, respectively, of the destination operand by powers of 2. For
>   example, using the SAR instruction to shift a signed integer 1 bit to
>   the right divides the value by 2.

By the way, this is a question in assembly, where these 2 operations are separated. In c, using the shift operator should be compiled to the appropriate type of operation based on the value type (signed on not)

Answer (score 0):

It has to be logical because you want all the bits to be right shifted.

Example:

1111 >> 2 should become 0011.
This is done via logical shift.

Arithmetic shift would give you 1111 >> 2 = 1001.

You can think of it as a kind of [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Comment: Your arithmetic shift example is incorrect, and your use of `>>` to denote arithmetic shifts is highly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common types of shift operator: arithmetic and logical.  The logical shift operators drop bits off one end and fill with zero bits at the other end.  The arithmetic shift drops bits at one end and fill the other end with copies of the bit that is already at that end.

Typically, logical shifts are available in both directions, but arithmetic shifts are available from the most significant bit to the least significant bit; i.e. from the left to the right.  (Certainly, that is the case in HLL languages that I'm aware of.  It may not apply universally; e.g. at the instruction set level for all ISAs.)

In Java<sup>1</sup>, `>>` is the arithmetic (sign extended) shift, and `>>>` is the logical (zero extended) shift.

Signed examples:

```
  00000010 >> 1   becomes 00000001  ( 2 becomes 1 )
  10000000 >> 1   becomes 11000000  ( -128 becomes -64 )
```

The purpose of arithmetic shifts is to deal with values where the bits represent a signed (2's complement) integer.  For example, `signed_value >> 1` is equivalent to dividing the value by 2.  This works, because the most significant bit (at the left end) of a 2's complement value is 1 for a negative value and zero for a non-negative value.

However, you are asking about unsigned values.  For such values, the most significant bit is not a sign bit, so division by 2 (from our example above) is performed as `unsigned_value >>> 1`.  Note: that is the logical shift operator.

If you wrote `unsigned_value >> 1` you would get an answer that is not the result of dividing the unsigned value by 2; i.e. the wrong answer ... for this problem.

Unsigned examples:

```
  00000010 >>> 1   becomes 00000001  ( 2 becomes 1 )
  10000000 >>> 1   becomes 01000000  ( 128 becomes 64 )
  10000000 >> 1    becomes 11000000  ( 128 becomes 196 ???? )
```

---

<sup>1 - In C++ `>>` is an arithmetic shift if the first operand type is signed, and a logical shift it is unsigned. In C the meaning of `>>` on a signed type is "implementation defined" ... according to the 2007 C standard.  Beware!</sup>